# Making keyframes ACTIVE?

Tags: keyframes

In the graph editor, I want to be able to quickly change F-curves from bezier to linear, etc., but it won't let me because the keyframe(s) are not "active." Simply selecting keyframes is insufficient to accomplish this. HOW do I make keyframes "active" so I can change their interpolation?

Comment: Why do you think they should be "active" ? Were all the keyframes which should be edited selected before changing interpolation ?

Comment: It was impossible to change interpolation because the selected keyframes were not "active."

Comment: Can you show screenshot of that instead of repeating what already is in the question ? Is that the text of error ? Show the screenshots of what have you done to change interpolation and what's gone wrong.